# Liferay issue in build-common-ivy.xml build failed

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp

[ivy:resolve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:resolve]   Server access error at url https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/biz/aQute/bnd/biz.aQute.bnd/2.4.1/biz.aQute.bnd-2.4.1.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect)
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\hooks\asset-publisher-hooks-hook\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\hooks\build-common-hook.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-plugin.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common.xml:57: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-ivy.xml:570: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-ivy.xml:173: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\shubham\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.10.1\build-common-ivy.xml:202: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 39 seconds

Comment: SO FAILED: impossible to determine question -- see [ask] for details

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has had issues recently w/ their CDN provider and have switched.

If you change your ivy-settings.xml to use https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ you should have no problems.